# specifying a ruby version in my Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Most tutorials I see have ruby '`2.0.0`' stated in their Gemfile

When I type `ruby -v` I get the following:

```
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]
```

Am I also okay with stating `ruby 2.0.0` or do I have to specify `ruby 2.0.0p195` ??

Comment: I don't think gem can handle patch number. Furthermode, patch is only for bug fixes, so there should not be backward incompatibility with it. Irrespective of that, relying on a particular patch number will make your system highly inflexible. It would mean that you cannot even apply security fixes. You should not do that.

Comment: There is no need to specify patch level..this will work if you specify ruby with version

Comment: @sawa: Bundler can do that since 1.5

Comment: @rkon I see. But as I commented, that should not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a ruby version on your Gemfile is just a way of telling to bundler: "please complain if there is a ruby version mismatch". To actually enforce which Ruby version should be used, you could use a ruby version manager such as [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/).

A different patchlevel (e.g. p195) won't cause you any issues but for the shake of completeness, since Bundler 1.5 you can specify a Ruby patchlevel with the following syntax:

```
ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => "195"
```

See the [Bundler 1.5 changelog](http://bundler.io/v1.5/whats_new.html#version15) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying just the Ruby version should work.

If you really have to restrict the patchlevel use:

```
ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => '195'
```